# sql addtime usage to increment time field

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use a variable to increment a time variable used in a stored sql procedure.

I have tried

```
v_start1 = addtime(v_start1, v_inc);

where:
declare v_start1 Time;
declare v_inc time; or declare v_inc varchar(10);

select start1 from table into v_start1;
select inc from another_table into v_inc;
```

and it fails to increment v_start1

If I use `v_start1 = addtime(v_start1, '00:15:00')` it works but `00:15:00` is a fixed value that needs to be changed

How do I go about using a second variable to supply the value to increment v_strar1 by
How do I **convert varchar to time**; the value may be in the form `+00:15` as a string

Answer (score 0):

Are the values coming from "another_table" strings like "+00:15" or Time data type values? This may be a problem.

I would recommend that you avoid using strings and only deal with them as either time or datetime data types. If you have a string like "+15:00" it may mean 15 minutes but it looks to some people like 15 hrs. Maybe in your query the value in the table is a string and is not getting converted correctly. Get it into the table as a Time field and it should work.

As a side note I like to work with a full DATETIME data type rather than Time types like you are doing when I have the need to add/subtract. If you are really only interested in Time, then just use the current day-month-year with your incoming time.

I am not 100% sure for MySql, but for SqlServer and Oracle it is possible to run into the following scenario:

If v_start1 is 23:55:00 and you add 15 minutes it actually becomes 00:00:10 of the next day. If you add 1455 minutes you get the exact same time but 2 days later. So, just looking at Time can get you in trouble.

If you deal with a DATETIME type then you can always use [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) and add whatever seconds, minutes, etc. easily.